# Switching from Full to Fast Syncmode in Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, fast-sync

I have been syncing my node for about 3 days now and am only at 39%. I assume part of that is my internet speed, and specs. However, I am wondering if I can pause geth, switch the service to use --fast and then continue from the block that I am currently at.

My concerns:

- Having to restart and not gaining any time
- Losing capabilties once fully synced (From what I have read, this is not valid as Geth switches to full mode as I reach the tip ;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually the biggest hurdle isn't internet speed but IOPS from the SSD. What was the geth command line? Are you sure geth is running in full mode? Since several years it isn't the default geth mode.

Comment: @Ismael my command line is:ExecStart=geth --datadir /your/path/chain/data --port your_port --syncmode "full" -cache=1024 --http --metrics --maxpeers 30